# Unit Testing with Stub & Mock Example

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I am new to testing.

I want to do unit testing with stub & mock in visual studio 2010.

Please provide any example or step by step guide for doing this.

Thanks

Comment: Need to be more specific. Do you have an example piece of code that you wish to test? Which stubbing and mocking framework are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Here's example how to use Moq

```
public interface IService
{
   string DoSomething(int i);
}

public class MyClass
{
   private readonly IService service;
   public MyClass(IService service)
   {
      this.service = service;
   }

   public string void Print()
   {
      var message = service.DoSomething();
      Console.WriteLine(message );
      return message;
   }

}

[Test]
public void TestSomething()
{
   var service = new Mock<IService>();
   service.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns("bla-bla");
   Assert.AreEqual("bla-bla", new MyClass(service).Print());
```

}

Comment: Minus one. No comments whatsoever. Add comments to help those new to the topic understand what's going on.

Answer (score -1):

NUnit
nmock
Moq
DotNetMock
these open source tool all provide mock funciton.